# Source Code vs Packaged App in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, open-source

I'm learning to code Ruby, starting to get into learning open source code. How do I turn the open source code I see on github to a runnable application? For example how do I turn source code from [Pomodori's Github](https://github.com/reborg/pomodori) to the downloadable app from [this page](http://reborg.github.io/pomodori/)? I'm interested in being able to manipulate the source code, and then convert it to a runnable app to see the changes. Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Pomodori is a MacRuby (http://macruby.org) application. But if you are just getting started, try something smaller/easier first.

Answer (score 1):

You can see Pomodori's only dependency (listed in it's Gemfile), is the **hotcococa** gem:

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem "hotcocoa"
```

Here is a tutorial for building a simple GUI application with [hotcocoa](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2010/11/22/build-a-mac-application-from-scratch-using-macruby-and-hotcocoa). Hotcocoa, as my fellow posters have pointed out is built on Macruby.

I think going directly with Macruby itself, is a better bet. There are lots of tutorials, and it is relatively up to date. You can build a simple [stopwatch](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby) app with macruby (full installation instructions are [here](https://github.com/MacRuby/MacRuby/wiki/Creating-a-simple-application)).

Personally if I was learning ruby again, I'd start with David Black's [The Well Grounded Rubyist](http://www.manning.com/black3/), or if you are looking for free resources, by working through the [bastards book](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com) or code academy's ruby course.

**update**: it occurred to me overnight that you may not be familiar with Ruby's REPL (read evaluate print loop) cli tool IRB, open terminal an enter:

```
$ irb
```

This loads an interactive ruby session, you can read more about irb [on Ruby's official site](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, Ruby isn't compiled, like C, C++, etc. -- it is executed directly from its source code.

Compilation in other languages is basically good for 1) converting as much of the app to machine code as possible, so it's faster at runtime and 2) removing the source code from the end result. There are ways to do both of these things to some extent in Ruby, but they are highly dependent on the specific Ruby implementation (e.g. MRI, JRuby, MacRuby) as well as the operating system the app will run on.

As Wukerplank notes, Pomodori is written in MacRuby, which is a Mac-specific implementation that has a tool called macruby-deploy that can make actual OS X apps. Unfortunately, the last time I checked (in early 2014), MacRuby didn't run correctly on OS X 10.9; its development mostly stalled out in the 10.7/10.8 era when its principal author (Laurent Sansonetti) created the commercial product [RubyMotion](http://www.rubymotion.com/). RubyMotion may be something you'd like to investigate if you don't mind yearly subscription fees; it additionally targets iOS and its apps can go in the App Store; it does sacrifice some of Ruby's dynamism, however.

But again, generally speaking people run Ruby programs by calling the Ruby interpreter on them  (e.g. `ruby program.rb`). Ruby interpreters these days do some just-in-time compilation to speed up execution, but the source code is still visible to the user of the code.